# Python - finding extracts the same values in a list and calculate the differences between consecutive values

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I am learning python on dataquest and trying to solve this problem.

Write a function that extracts the same values across years and calculates the differences between consecutive values to show if number of births is increasing or decreasing.
For example, how did the number of births on Saturday change each year between 1994 and 2003?

I am trying to solve this in Jupyter. I am new to python and I am not sure how to get started on this problem.

The data input is here in CSV format : [US births](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/blob/master/births/US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv)

```
    # coding: utf-8

# In[1]:

text_file = open("US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv", "r").read()
line_split = text_file.split("\n")
line_split


# In[2]:

def read_csv(filename):
    text = open(filename, "r").read()
    string_list = text.split('\n')[1:]
    final_list = []
    for row in string_list:
        int_fields = []
        string_fields = row.split(',')
        for item in string_fields:
            int_fields.append(int(item))
        final_list.append(int_fields)
    return(final_list)

cdc_list = read_csv("US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv")
cdc_list[0:10]


# In[3]:

def months_births(filename):
    births_per_month = dict()
    for item in filename:
        num_month = int(item[1])
        num_births = int(item[4])
        if num_month in births_per_month:
            births_per_month[num_month] += num_births
        else:
            births_per_month[num_month] = num_births
    return(births_per_month)

cdc_month_births = months_births(cdc_list)
cdc_month_births


# In[4]:

def dow_births(filename):
    sum_births = dict()
    for item in filename:
        day_week = int(item[3])
        day_birth = int(item[4])
        if day_week in sum_births:
            sum_births[day_week] += day_birth
        else:
            sum_births[day_week] = day_birth
    return(sum_births)

cdc_day_births = dow_births(cdc_list)
cdc_day_births


# In[30]:

def calc_counts(data, column):
    sum_dict = dict()
    for item in data:
        col_num = item[column]
        birth_count = int(item[4])
        if col_num in sum_dict:
            sum_dict[col_num] += birth_count
        else:
            sum_dict[col_num] = birth_count
    return(sum_dict)

cdc_year_births = calc_counts(cdc_list, 0)
cdc_month_births = calc_counts(cdc_list, 1)
cdc_dom_births = calc_counts(cdc_list, 2)
cdc_dow_births = calc_counts(cdc_list, 3)


# In[31]:

cdc_year_births


# In[32]:

cdc_month_births


# In[33]:

cdc_dom_births


# In[34]:

cdc_dow_births


# In[6]:

def min_max_dict(filename, request):
    if request == "max":
        max_value = max(filename, key=filename.get)
        return(filename[max_value])
    else:
        min_value = min(filename, key=filename.get)
        return(filename[min_value])

max_value = min_max_dict(cdc_year_births, "max")
print("max: ",max_value)
min_value = min_max_dict(cdc_year_births, "min")
print("min: ",min_value)


# In[36]:

def diff_in_values(filename):
    final_dict = dict()
    seen_set = set()
    unique_values = list()
    for item in filename:
        year_count = int(item[0])
        birth_count = int(item[4])
        day_of_week = int(item[3])

        if birth_count not in seen_set:
            unique_values.append(birth_count)
            seen_set.add(birth_count)

    return(seen_set)

result = diff_in_values(cdc_list)
result
```

Comment: You get started by clarifying the requirements. What is the data format of the years and the number of births (both the format of the data itself and how it is stored with other data)? How can your function access that data? What is the desired format of the output? Are there any other requirements or preferences? We cannot possibly help you until you get and understand those requirements then include them in your question. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Many thanks. I've included more information in the question. Please let me know if this is not enough.

Comment: More is needed about the input, and you have said nothing about the output. Is that csv file on your drive in the same folder as your function module? Is that file guaranteed to have that name, to have exactly one line for each day from 1994-01-01 through 2003-12-31, for the lines to be in chronological order with no repeated or missing days, for the header line and data lines to be complete and properly formatted, etc.? Is that question about Saturday births the only output needed? And so on. And you do realize that your code does not actually access the data?

Comment: Yes to your questions. I am using project Jupyter for learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also working on the same project. I've shared the part of the code you need. I have my .ipynb file of the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/Nocks/US-Births/blob/master/us-births.ipynb). You may want to also see my outcome of the function. Cheers!

```
def read_csv(birth_data_file):
    raw_data = open(birth_data_file, "r").read()
    raw_data = raw_data.split("\n")
    string_list = raw_data[1:]
    final_list = []
    for data in string_list:
        int_fields = []
        string_fields = data.split(",")
        for string_field in string_fields:
            field = int(string_field)
            int_fields.append(field)
        final_list.append(int_fields)
    return(final_list)


def calc_counts(data, column):
    births_counts = {}
    if not column > 0 and column <= 4:
        return("'column' must be either 1, 2, 3, or 4")
    else:
        for instance in data:
            field = instance[column-1]
            births  = instance[4]
            if field in births_counts.keys():
                births_counts[field] += births
            else:
                births_counts[field] = births
        return(births_counts)


# Write a function that extracts the same values across years and calculates the
# differences between consecutive values to show if number of
# births is increasing or decreasing.

def check_birth_growth(birth_data_file):
    cdc_list = read_csv(birth_data_file)
    cdc_year_births = calc_counts(cdc_list, 1)
    previous_year_birth = 0
    previous_birth_diff = 0
    for year, total_births in cdc_year_births.items():
        current_year_birth = int(total_births)
        if previous_year_birth == 0:
            growth_status = "Growth of births in {} not available.".format(year)
            print(growth_status)
            previous_year_birth = current_year_birth
        else:
            if current_year_birth > previous_year_birth:
                growth_status = "Births increased in {}.".format(year)
                print(growth_status)
                previous_year_birth = current_year_birth
            elif current_year_birth < previous_year_birth:
                growth_status = "Births decreased in {}.".format(year)
                print(growth_status)
                previous_year_birth = current_year_birth
            elif current_year_birth == previous_year_birth:
                growth_status = "Births in {} was same as previous year.".format(year)
                print(growth_status)
                previous_year_birth = current_year_birth
```

Comment: Hey @iprateekk! It's a pleasure! :)

Comment: Thank you. you really helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
def calc_diff(filename, date_one, date_two, column, column_value):
birth_rate_result = []
previous_birth_rate = 0

for row in filename:
    year = row[0]
    current_birth_rate = row[4]
    time_unit = row[column]
    if year in range(date_one,date_two):
        if time_unit is column_value:
            birth_rate_diff = (current_birth_rate - previous_birth_rate)
            if birth_rate_diff > 0:
                growth_status = "increased"
                previous_birth_rate = current_birth_rate
            elif birth_rate_diff < 0:
                growth_status = "decreased"
                previous_birth_rate = current_birth_rate
            elif birth_rate_diff == 0:
                growth_status = "static"
                previous_birth_rate = current_birth_rate

            birth_rate_result.append([birth_rate_diff, growth_status,row[0]])

return birth_rate_result
```

## I just started learning the python, can you please tell me how to run these code example (birth_diffrence = calc_diff(cdc_list,4,4,0,4)) no answer is pop up.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the above codes only tally the difference of births between consecutive years, period, without giving the opportunity to do it for different parameters -for example, differences of births over years in January or on Sunday

In the below function you can do this e.g. see the differences over years for births on Monday with inputs: **column** = 3 and **value** = 1

```
def delta_year(input_list, column, value): # Column to loop over, value to compare over years

    column_year_count = {} # Create dictionary to get attribute yearly count

    for each in input_list:
        attribute = each[column]
        year = each[0]
        births = each[4]
        if attribute == value:
            if year in column_year_count:
                column_year_count[year] += births
            else:
                column_year_count[year] = births

    column_year_count_list = [] # Create list to order years to get consecutive years

    for key, value in column_year_count.items():
        temp = [key,value]
        column_year_count_list.append(temp)

    column_year_delta = {} # Create dictionary to insert ordered years & delta values

    for i in range(0,len(column_year_count_list)): # Loop over list index
        for j in range(0,len(column_year_count_list)): # Loop over second list index
            delta_year = column_year_count_list[j][0] - column_year_count_list[i][0] # Tally delta between years
            if delta_year == 1: # Select consecutive years only
                delta_year_births = column_year_count_list[j][1] - column_year_count_list[i][1]
                column_year_delta[column_year_count_list[j][0]] = delta_year_births
    return column_year_delta
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of your code saying why your solution is the better one, or else you might not get votes. It would also help new coders understand what you have done.